# Spectrum of non compact operator is 0

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Can you please help me to give an example of non compact operator which spectrum is {0}

Comment: $\{0\}$, not 0.

Answer (score 4):

Write an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ as $\mathcal H_1  \oplus \mathcal H_2$, where $U: \mathcal H_1 \to \mathcal H_2$ is an isomorphism.  Let $T$ be the operator defined by $T(v_1 + v_2) = U v_1$ where $v_1 \in \mathcal H_1$ and $v_2 \in \mathcal H_2$.
Then $T^2 = 0$ so $\sigma(T) = \{0\}$, but $\text{Ran}(T) = \mathcal H_1$ is closed and infinite-dimensional so $T$ is not compact.